# Как получить выбранный элемент из spinner привязанного к БД

Tags: android-spinner, java, android

Получить я его получила но коряво:

```
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            String cursor;
            if (position == 0) {
                cursor = CursorConstr.getString(CursorConstr.getInt(parent
                        .getSelectedItemPosition()));
            } else
                curscon = CursorConstr.getString(parent
                        .getSelectedItemPosition());

            Log.d("myLogs", "constr: " + curscon);
        }
```

В лог выводит все правильно, но что-то мне не нравится что с условиями... Как-нибудь можно без условий обойтись? Если его просто убрать то на 0 позиции выдает просто id элемента...

Comment: у вас случаем опечатки в коде нет? что за curscon?

Answer (score 1):

Если поставщиком данных является SQLite БД, то в `id`, который приходит в `onItemSelected()` пишется идентификатор записи в БД - точнее значение предопределенного поля `_ID`, так что сразу дергайте из `Cursor` по идентификатору нужную запись.